# How to cancel JSON request when sending a new jsonrequest to server

Tags: jquery

When the user type something in textbox the auto-complete work with json, he make lots of requests to the server. How can I stop the old request when making a new request in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you fire those `json request` over a `XMLHttpRequest` object or in other words, you're using `.ajax()`. You can in general cancel an ajax request by using `.abort()`.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({});

// somewhere else
if(xhr)
   xhr.abort();
```

since `.ajax()` returns the original `XHR` event you can store that somewhere and abort that request.
Of course you would have to create somekind of "request logic" to handle this stuff. Example:

```
var xhrmanager = function() {
    var requests = [],
        self     = {};

    self.create  = function(params, cb){
        if(typeof params === 'object') {// additional checks here
           var xhr = $.ajax($.extend({
               url:      '/path/script.pl',
               dataType: 'json',
               type:     'GET',
               success:  function(data, status, req){
                    if(typeof cb === 'function')
                       cb.apply(this, [data]);                        
               },
               complete: function(req, status) {
                    var pos = $.inArray(req, requests);

                    if(pos > -1)
                       requests.splice(pos, 1)
               }
           }, params || {}));
        }
    };
    self.clearAll = function(){
        for(var i = 0, len = requests.length; i < len; i++){
           requests[i].abort();
        }
    };

    return self;
};
```

usage like:

```
var json_requests = xhrmanager();

json_requests.create({
   data:  'some=data'
}, function(data) {
   // do something
});

json_requests.clearAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

a first, basic, attempt would be: just make a small offset (eg. 100ms) for the request. so you just need to reset the timer each time a key is pressed.

eg.

```
var timeout;
var textBox = $('#textbox');
textBox.change(function() {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    var callingMethod = /* insert your method for the request */;
    timeout = setTimeout(callingMethod, 100);
});
```

second attempt would be: the request should be a variable. each time you enter your request-logic check the variable against null (some kind of: double locking pattern). so if the variable is not null, you know that a request is going on. hence you store the old request in the variable you can cancel it.

eg.

```
var request;
function DoMagicThing() {
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
        request = null;
    }

    request = $.ajax({
        /* insert options here */,
        complete = function() {
            request = null;
        }
    });
}
```